# Compare and update two arrays without losing mutated data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filtering

I have an array of objects contains data of persons

```
const oldArr = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Alex',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'John',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Jack',
    }
]
```

then I add data to this array to each element where I end up with new key called money with value of 20 as the following

```
oldArr.map((el, index) => el.money = 20)
```

and the array becomes like this

```
...
{
   id: 2,
   name: 'John',
   money: 20
},
...
```

Now, I have a new array with new data (new person) but missing the money I have added before. (careful person with id 2 is not there)

```
const newArr = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Alex',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Jack',
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Chris',
    },
]
```

I want to update the old array with new data but also keep the mutated data, and I want the result to end up like this:

```
const result = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Alex',
        money: 20
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Jack',
        money: 20
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Chris',
    },
]
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a note: `map` creates a whole new array, it doesn't make sense to use it for just mutating the contents. Use `forEach` or just a regular for loop instead.

```js
oldArr.forEach((el) => (el.money = 20));
```

The following will give you the intended result:

```js
const result = newArr.map(
  (newEl) => oldArr.find((el) => el.id === newEl.id) || newEl
);
```

The OR operator `||` returns the second argument if the first is falsey.

---

You can optimize this by mapping items by id instead of brute force searching the old array.

```js
const idMap = new Map();
oldArr.forEach((el) => {
  el.money = 20;
  idMap.set(el.id, el);
});
```

```js
const result = newArr.map((newEl) => idMap.get(newEl.id) || newEl);
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-f3sw8w?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

If I getted it clear you are just trying to iterate throw the items of array generating a new array with the property "money" added to each one.

If so the map is the best option, just assign it to a new variable and change the item before return the element like bellow.

```js
const oldArr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Alex"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "John"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Jack"
  }
];

const newArr = oldArr.map((el) => {
  el.money = "20";
  return el;
});

console.log(oldArr);
console.log(newArr);
```

In this way you'll be able to keep both arrays.

If wasn't this, pls let me know.

Comment: No, I get the new array response from a server

Answer (score 0):

Just merge the objects:

```
const result = oldArr.map((person) => ({
    ...person,
    ...newArr.find((cur) => cur.id === person.id),
}));
```

Comment: that won't do it because in the new array I have a person that no longer exists

Comment: So, iterate the new array instead of the old one.